# i am trying to transform this function that retrieves user data from a firestore database using this function

Tags: swift

I am trying to transform this function so that instead of Printing the `firstname`, it would instead return it. My goal here is to have a return value so that I can attach the output to a textLabel. Therefore I would have:

```
WelcomeLabel.text = getDocument()
```

I don't know if this is the right approach, I would appreciate some guidance.

```
private func getDocument() {
    //Get sspecific document from current user
    let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")

    // Get data
    docRef.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        } else if querySnapshot!.documents.count != 1 {
            print("More than one documents or none")
        } else {
            let document = querySnapshot!.documents.first
            let dataDescription = document?.data()
            guard let firstname = dataDescription?["firstname"] else { return }
            print(firstname)
        }
    }
}
```

i am trying to get the current users firstname and type (Welcome, 'firstname') on a textLabel in a view controller

Comment: Returning a value from a function is a fundamental aspect of a programming language. You should really start here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/GuidedTour/GuidedTour.html